# Compute the double integral $\int_0^\infty \int _{x/\sqrt{4kt}}^\infty y^2 e^{-y^2} dy\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have to compute:

$$\int_0^\infty \int _\frac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}} ^\infty y^2 e^{-y^2} dy\, dx, $$ where $k$ and $t$ are two constants.

I want to use the fact that $\int_0 ^\infty y^2 e^{-y^2} dy dx =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} $, but I don't know how to do it!

Any help ?

Comment: I think you could use diff. under the integral sign better. $$y^2\mathrm{e}^{-y^2} = -\lim_{\alpha \to 1}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha y^2}$$

Comment: "I want to use the fact that..." Why, one wonders. Instead, exchange the order of integration to deduce that the double integral is, with $c=\sqrt{4kt}$, $$\int_0^\infty \int _0^{cy}y^2 e^{-y^2} dx\, dy=c\int_0^\infty y^3 e^{-y^2} dy=\frac{c}2\int_0^\infty ze^{-z} dz, $$ with the change of variables $z=y^2$, and conclude that the double integral is $$\frac{c}2=\sqrt{kt}.$$.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of integration to get

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^2 \, e^{-y^2} \int_0^{y \sqrt{4 k t}} dx = \sqrt{4 k t} \int_0^{\infty} dy \, y^3 \, e^{-y^2} = \sqrt{k t} \int_0^{\infty} du \, u \, e^{-u} = \sqrt{k t}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a>0$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{\frac{x}{a}}^{+\infty}y^2 e^{-y^2}\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{+\infty} x^3 y^2 e^{-x^2 y^2}\,dy \,dx = \int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2y^2}\,dy=\frac{a}{2}. $$